# How to display the same control on two different tabs?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, controls, tabcontrol

I'm using VB.NET

I need same control (ListBox) to be displayed on 2 different tabs.

Is it mandatory to create 2 different ListBox instances?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you don't need design-time support you can simply, at runtime, change the ListBox instance's Parent from one tab to the other (making sure to set the positioning appropriately, of course).

Essentially, it's:

`listBox1.Parent = tabControl1.TabPages[1];`

In the end though, you'll probably find it easier to just have two ListBox's with the same data source.

Comment: That's the way to do :) I had to cope with a similar situation where different usercontrol instances had to be displayed in tabs, plus a same single control instance which had to appear on every tab. I used the same `.Parent` property trick as you, using a Panel placeholder inside the control instead of the TabPage : it works fine.

Comment: I did not expect it to be this simple to move a tabpage between tabcontrols :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think you'll need a ListBox control on each tab.  If they have the same data you can use the same DataSource for both though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, add a new instance on each tab.

Answer (score 1):

If you want full designer support, you'll need two boxes.  If doing it in code is enough, you can create a single listbox on form load, and manually add a reference to it to each tab page.