# Is there a way to put the same control in different tabs using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabcontrol

Is there a way to put the same control in different tabs using C#?

Comment: post some code. wat u exactly like to do

Comment: Using some deep magic - definitely. But maybe it's a good idea to put it outside the tabcontrol?

Comment: Magic needed isn't that deep, simply change it's parent to the current tab and you're all set.

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513276/how-to-display-the-same-control-on-two-different-tabs?rq=1) gives the trick. You will allways have only one instance of such a control. The tip is to tell him to which .Parent it should hook : you change this when you switch from one to the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Any control can only have a single parent. What would be the control's location if it were in two places, too?

I would suggest you have two controls which have a common "core" object which contains everything you genuinely want to share between the two controls.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot place the same instance of a control in two different tabs, but you could create a custom user control that contains the controls you want in each tab, then populate each tab with an instance of that user control.

Microsoft's [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6h7e207%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on creating custom user controls is quite good, in my opinion.